# WithStyles not working in Material UI for React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an app using Material UI Beta where I try to style a simple component as follows:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider } from 'material-ui/styles';


const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: 200,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: 200,
  },
  menu: {
    width: 200,
  },
});



export const CreateJob = (props) => {
  const { classes } = props;
  let confirmDelete = () => {
    const r = window.confirm("Confirm deletion of job");
    return r === true;
  };

  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={props.isEditting ? props.handleEdit : props.handleSubmit}  noValidate autoComplete="off">
          <h2>Update job details</h2>
          <TextField
            error={props.jobIdError !== ''}
            helperText={props.jobIdError || "Example: ES10"}
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="jobId"
            label="Job ID"
            name="jobid"
            fullWidth
            onChange={props.handleInputChange('jobId')}
            value={props.jobId} />
         </form>
       </div>
     </MultiThemeProvider>
```

I then use this in my parent component as follows:

```
<CreateJob open={this.state.open} />
```

However, this yields the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'classes' of undefined

Comment: how did you pass your props?

Comment: as I see you don't need classes prop, why are you passing it, or how?

Comment: Does `this.state.open` contains `classes` property? if not try adding an empty object to it!

Comment: Sorry, I missed a key line at the end of my componenet: export default withStyles(styles)(CreateJob); This is intended to pass the styles to the props but it throws the error above. I got the approach from this example: https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/ but without luck

Comment: I am having the same problem, any ones find a solution?

Comment: @user3642173 does it work when you omit `const { classes } = props`? Because it seems like it sees `props` as undefined, so it has nothing to do with `withStyles`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.state is not defined in your code. In the example, state is defined as

```
    state = {
    name: 'Cat in the Hat',
    age: '',
    multiline: 'Controlled',
    currency: 'EUR',
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm kinda late with an answer, but I just found this question while searching for another solution.

I'm going to assume you also imported `withStyles`.

Firstly, you don't need to export both the simple component and the enhanced one:

```
export const CreateJob = props => {...} // lose the 'export'
export default withStyles(styles)(CreateJob); // only export here
```

Secondly, a real problem: `<MuiThemeProvider>` should be placed around your highest component(usually the `<App>` component that you render in your entry point file), so you can customize the default theme to your liking for the whole app; see their example [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/bd24e74a98144870d2a5513abb1c0288c2aff254/examples/with-material-ui-next/components/App.js). I'm not sure, but this might even solve your problem, since that should have thrown another error like in this [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7393).

I just hope this helps someone, but I cannot be sure about what your exact problem is without the complete component file.

Comment: Often, people like exporting the unstyled component to simplify testing